# Getting database results where no records on joined table

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

How do I get results, where there are no results on the joined table, but only for that user?

For example:

```
    $availableQuests = Upload::where('uploads.approved', 1)
        ->where('uploads.published', 1)
        ->where('uploads.available', 1)
        ->where('uploads.type', 'guide')
        ->join('completed_guides', 'uploads.id', '=', 'completed_guides.upload_id')
        ->whereNull('completed_guides.id')
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

The problem with this, this accounts for all users, I need to include `completed_guides.user_id` somehow, to get all the uploads where the id doesnt match in `completed_guides`

If that makes sense?

Comment: `leftJoin` instead of `join`?

Comment: ...or two different  queries if the requirements are different?